# jQuery: mouseup + position: absolute + show(). Problems in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mouseup

I am trying to implement a popup that appears when user selects some text in specific `<div>`.
The tooltip is a `<div>` with `display: none` and `position: absolute` CSS properties at the bottom of the page.

In mouseup event handler for selectable div I am doing the following:

```
$("#popup").css({
    top: e.pageY,
    left: e.pageX
}).show();
```

Here's a working JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6r4Lrgmv/

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but Internet Explorer (I have tested on version 9 and 11) selects text on page till the bottom. What am I doing wrong? Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: maybe try `top: e.pageX + 'px', left: e.pageX + 'px'`

Comment: that's your fiddle who didn't work on IE or your original page ?

Comment: The fiddle is working fine for me on IE11 x64 running on Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

Comment: Freez, both fiddle and original page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guessed explanation: when showing the popup, IE thinks your mouse cursor is actually inside the popup. So it selects the text to the end of the page.

I found two possible solutions (tested with IE 11):

- Add +1 to the popup position. This way the popup does not appear directly under the mouse cursor.

  ```
  $("#popup").css({
      top: e.pageY + 1,
      left: e.pageX + 1
  }).show();
  ```
- Use setTimeout. This way the popup is shown after the event is finished (at the end of the current event queue).

  ```
  setTimeout(function() {
      $("#popup").css({
          top: e.pageY,
          left: e.pageX
      }).show();
  });
  ```

Comment: Vote up, because this doesn't make much sense .. which is exactly how you debug for IE :D